# pyspark error with reduceByKey call using simple wordcount from a file

Tags: pyspark

Trying to run this pyspark wordcount program from this page: https://www.learntospark.com/2020/01/word-count-program-in-apache-spark.html

Here is my code:

```
import findspark
findspark.init()

# Create SparkSession and sparkcontext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder\
                    .master("spark://my-ubuntu.xxx.com:7077")\
                    .appName('wordcount')\
                    .getOrCreate()
sc=spark.sparkContext

# Read the input file and Calculating words count
text_file = sc.textFile("peterpan.txt")
counts = text_file.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")) \
                            .map(lambda word: (word, 1)) \
                           .reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y)

# Printing each word with its respective count
output = counts.collect()
for (word, count) in output:
    print("%s: %i" % (word, count))
    

# Stopping Spark-Session and Spark context
sc.stop()
spark.stop()
```

I am getting following error:  ***tuple index out of range.***
I am trying to learn pyspark. Any help is appreciated.

```
PicklingError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [9], line 16
     12 # Read the input file and Calculating words count
     13 text_file = sc.textFile("peterpan1.txt")
     14 counts = text_file.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")) \
     15                             .map(lambda word: (word, 1)) \
---> 16                            .reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y)
     18 # Printing each word with its respective count
     19 output = counts.collect()

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\rdd.py:2275, in RDD.reduceByKey(self, func, numPartitions, partitionFunc)
   2252 def reduceByKey(
   2253     self: "RDD[Tuple[K, V]]",
   2254     func: Callable[[V, V], V],
   2255     numPartitions: Optional[int] = None,
   2256     partitionFunc: Callable[[K], int] = portable_hash,
   2257 ) -> "RDD[Tuple[K, V]]":
   2258     """
   2259     Merge the values for each key using an associative and commutative reduce function.
   2260 
   (...)
   2273     [('a', 2), ('b', 1)]
   2274     """
-> 2275     return self.combineByKey(lambda x: x, func, func, numPartitions, partitionFunc)
```

..

```
File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\rdd.py:3345, in _prepare_for_python_RDD(sc, command)
   3342 def _prepare_for_python_RDD(sc: "SparkContext", command: Any) -> Tuple[bytes, Any, Any, Any]:
   3343     # the serialized command will be compressed by broadcast
   3344     ser = CloudPickleSerializer()
-> 3345     pickled_command = ser.dumps(command)
   3346     assert sc._jvm is not None
   3347     if len(pickled_command) > sc._jvm.PythonUtils.getBroadcastThreshold(sc._jsc):  # Default 1M
   3348         # The broadcast will have same life cycle as created PythonRDD

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\serializers.py:468, in CloudPickleSerializer.dumps(self, obj)
    466     msg = "Could not serialize object: %s: %s" % (e.__class__.__name__, emsg)
    467 print_exec(sys.stderr)
--> 468 raise pickle.PicklingError(msg)

PicklingError: Could not serialize object: IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

=== peterpan.txt file is story with 6k+ lines. Bunch of lines from the file are listed below. =====

The Project Gutenberg EBook of Peter Pan, by James M. Barrie

This eBook is for the use of anyone anywhere at no cost and with
almost no restrictions whatsoever.  You may copy it, give it away or
re-use it under the terms of the Project Gutenberg License included
with this eBook or online at [www.gutenberg.org](http://www.gutenberg.org)

** This is a COPYRIGHTED Project Gutenberg eBook, Details Below **
**     Please follow the copyright guidelines in this file.     **

Title: Peter Pan
Peter Pan and Wendy

Author: James M. Barrie

Posting Date: June 25, 2008 [EBook #16]
Release Date: July, 1991
Last Updated: October 14, 2016

Language: English

Character set encoding: UTF-8

*** START OF THIS PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK PETER PAN ***

PETER PAN

[PETER AND WENDY]

By J. M. Barrie [James Matthew Barrie]

A Millennium Fulcrum Edition (c)1991 by Duncan Research

Contents:

Chapter 1 PETER BREAKS THROUGH

Chapter 2 THE SHADOW
..
..
EBooks posted prior to November 2003, with eBook numbers BELOW #10000,
are filed in directories based on their release date.  If you want to
download any of these eBooks directly, rather than using the regular
search system you may utilize the following addresses and just
download by the etext year.

http://www.ibiblio.org/gutenberg/etext06

```
(Or /etext 05, 04, 03, 02, 01, 00, 99,
 98, 97, 96, 95, 94, 93, 92, 92, 91 or 90)
```

EBooks posted since November 2003, with etext numbers OVER #10000, are
filed in a different way.  The year of a release date is no longer part
of the directory path.  The path is based on the etext number (which is
identical to the filename).  The path to the file is made up of single
digits corresponding to all but the last digit in the filename.  For
example an eBook of filename 10234 would be found at:

http://www.gutenberg.org/1/0/2/3/10234

or filename 24689 would be found at:
http://www.gutenberg.org/2/4/6/8/24689

An alternative method of locating eBooks:
http://www.gutenberg.org/GUTINDEX.ALL

*** END: FULL LICENSE ***

Comment: Please provide a sample of data. On my side your code is running as is.

Comment: It is story with 6k+ lines. Let me add bunch of lines from beginning and end to my question above.

Comment: Your code still works with : http://www.gutenberg.org/2/4/6/8/24689